# Form validation in javascript does not work probably

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I am working on this form which is suppose to validate the form before submitting

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form3").validate();
    if ($('#form3').valid()) $('#form3').submit();
});
```

But the problem is: it prints the (empty fields error) when the form is loaded.

---

UPDATE : the function is now working Horraaay :) with the following code:

```
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#form3").validate();
     });
     </script>
```

The only problem was the input form name .. I used  'submit' as a name of the input form however before was on different name.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code on the form submit event. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#form3").validate();
    $("#form3").submit(function(event)    
    {
        if (!$(this).valid()) 
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No need to use *both* `preventDefault` and `return false`.

Comment: `$(this).validate` initializes the plugin, I think you want to do it earlier.

Comment: yes, `return false = event.preventDefault + event.stopPropagation`

Answer (score 0):

I think by default after successful validation it will submit the form . However i don't know why you need to resubmit the form.

If you need to submit manually you can use the SubmitHandler place to submit your form.

```
$("#form3").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {       
     form.submit();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and now it works ...
It is a minor error !

I changed the submit button name and id to ( Submit).