# jQuery form validation validate() the submitting does not work after the validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Form validation in javascripit does not work propably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598702/form-validation-in-javascripit-does-not-work-propably)

I used the `validate()` to validate the form.

Here is the html:

```
    <form  id="form3" name="form3"   method="post" action="changepassExcution.php">
           <ul>  <li id="foli1" class="notranslate">

                    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="oldpass">
            old password:
           </label>
                <div>
                   <input id="oldpass" name="oldpass" type="password" class="field text medium    required" maxlength="255" tabindex="1"/> </div></li>
 <li id="foli2" class="notranslat">
                <label class="desc" id="title2" for="newpass">
                              new password:
                         </label>
                           <div>
               <input id="newpass" name="newpass" type="password" class="field text medium  required" maxlength="255" tabindex="2" />
            </div></li>
       <li id="foli3" class="notranslate">
       <label class="desc" id="title3" for="retypenewpass">
      repeat new password:</label>
          <div><input id="retypenewpass" name="retypenewpass" type="password" class="field text medium required"  maxlength="255" tabindex="3" /></div></li>
        <li class="buttons "><div>
            <input  id="saveForm" name="saveForm" class="button" type="submit" value="change password"/></div></li>

            </ul>
             </form>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form3").validate();
       });
       </script>
```

The problem is: when I submit the form correctly (valid), it will be submitted, but when the form is invalid, then I correct it the submit doesn't work.

---

UPDATE : the function is now working Horraaay :) with the following code :

```
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#form3").validate();
     });
     </script>
```

The only problem was the input form name .. I used  'submit' as a name of the input form however before was on diffrient name..

Comment: if my suggestion doesn't work, could you show us.validate() function? unless you are using validate plugin?

Comment: Try writing the validate functionality in $('#form1').submit() and see if that works.

Comment: @Shant it does not work when i did that

Comment: You have already asked the same question just a few hours ago, please edit the old question to match your current progress rather than making new question every time something changes a bit.

Comment: When you say, it does not work...does is give any error? In case Yes, plz post the error message.

Comment: @Shant it does not work means when i press sumbit button nothing changes .. while  it suppose do the action

Comment: And there is no error as well?

Comment: @Shant NO firebug does not indicates any errors

Comment: Can you share little code with us to help you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#form3").validate();
    });
</script>
```

**edit**

try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#form3").submit(function(){
            $(this).validate();
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yup this is just i typing error when i paste it here  .. i edited it .. the problem is not from it

Comment: now it does not work at all . :(

Comment: do you get any errors? are you using firebug? if not i'd suggest getting firebug, then on error reporting turn on persist so that it will stay there even if the page reloads. Then let us know

Comment: use your code and then see if there is an error? Also you defo using persist?

Comment: yes i debugged it there is no error

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that it works, but there are no rules for validation - so it always passes?

How about setting some rules like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form3").validate({
        rules: {
            oldpass: { required: true },
            newpass: { required: true },                
        }
    });
});
```

Read more in [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate)